# Align Highcharts bars right

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I used the `opposite` attribute to move the xAxis to the right. How is it possible that the bars will also start on the right side?

Thanks!

```js
Highcharts.chart('absoluteInterruptions', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    rotate: -90
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Absolute Interruptions'
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    opposite: true,
    categories: [
      'Linie5007',
      'Linie5007.ST405',
      'Linie5007.ST406',
      'Linie5007.ST407',
      'Linie5007.ST408',
      'Linie5007.ST409',
      'Linie5007.ST410',
      'Linie5007.ST411',
      'Linie5007.ST412',
      'Linie5007.ST413'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    align: 'right',
    name: 'Interruptions',
    data: [19, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'right',
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<div id='absoluteInterruptions'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.reversed) from the documentation and managed to get it to work by setting

`yAxis:{reversed:true}`

By reversing the y-axis the bars go from right to left.

```js
Highcharts.chart('absoluteInterruptions', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    rotate: -90
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Absolute Interruptions'
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    opposite: true,
    categories: [
      'Linie5007',
      'Linie5007.ST405',
      'Linie5007.ST406',
      'Linie5007.ST407',
      'Linie5007.ST408',
      'Linie5007.ST409',
      'Linie5007.ST410',
      'Linie5007.ST411',
      'Linie5007.ST412',
      'Linie5007.ST413'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    reversed: true,
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    align: 'right',
    name: 'Interruptions',
    data: [19, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'right',
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<div id='absoluteInterruptions'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry but it's hard to find things in the highcharts docs if youre new to highcharts